# Could a $uuuu\bar{u}$ pentaquark exist?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, pauli-exclusion-principle, pentaquarks

Could a $uuuu\bar{u}$ pentaquark exist or is it forbidden due to Pauli exclusion principle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's any obstruction due to Pauli Exclusion to writing down a local operator that looks like it may excite a $uuuu\overline{u}$-type pentaquark, for example you could write something like:
$$ \mathcal{O}^{\mu,i,j} = \epsilon_{abc} u_a^\mu (u_b^T C \gamma_i u_c) (\overline{u} \gamma_j u)$$
where an appropriate projection will give you something that lives in a spin-5/2 representation. This operator is not identically zero by Pauli exclusion, so it seems like a candidate. Even if you asked for a $uuuuuuuu\cdots uuuuu$ type hadron - you could still write down an operator that seemed to excite such a state; the operator would necessarily have to be nonlocal (to avoid Pauli Exclusion principle issues), but that's ok.

There's no reason to expect that there is an actual pentaquark *state* with those quantum numbers though. More likely - this operator will just overlap onto $\rho \Delta^{++}$ two-particle states.